# PostThreadMessage doesn't work

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, event-handling, peekmessage

I have an event-handling thread class which allows me to raise events from other threads without interrupting their operation. When the destructor is called I send a quit message to the thread, but its message loop doesn't seem to receive this message.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <windows.h>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#define ET_EVENTPUSH 7854
#define ET_QUITLOOP 6581
#define EVENT_HANDLER void
typedef void (*EVENT)(LPVOID);

//# event handler thread
class event_thread
{
private:
    //vars
    HANDLE  m_thread;   //event loop thread
    DWORD   m_id;       //thread id

    //thread procedure
    static DWORD WINAPI listener_loop(LPVOID);

public:
    //constructor
    event_thread();
    ~event_thread();

    //functions
    void push_event(EVENT, LPVOID);
};

//# event handler thread
event_thread::event_thread()
{
    //create thread
    m_thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, listener_loop, NULL, 0, &m_id); 
}
event_thread::~event_thread()
{
    DWORD dw;

    //stop thread
    if (m_thread)
    {
        dw = GetLastError(); 
        PostThreadMessage(m_id, ET_QUITLOOP, 0, 0);
        dw = GetLastError(); 
        WaitForSingleObject(m_thread, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(m_thread);
    }
}

void event_thread::push_event(EVENT e, LPVOID p)
{
    PostThreadMessage(m_id, ET_EVENTPUSH, (UINT)e, (UINT)p);
}
DWORD WINAPI event_thread::listener_loop(LPVOID param)
{
    MSG     msg;
    #define event_type  msg.message
    #define event_call  ((EVENT)(msg.wParam))
    #define event_param (LPVOID)(msg.lParam)

    //while thread is alive
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        switch (event_type)
        {
        case ET_EVENTPUSH:
            event_call(event_param);
            break;
        case ET_QUITLOOP:
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

EVENT_HANDLER asda(LPVOID as)
{
    cout << (int)as << endl;
}

int main()
{
    event_thread thr;

    int i = 1;
    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_NUMPAD1))
    {
        thr.push_event(asda, (LPVOID)(i++));
        Sleep(20);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`GetMessage` doesn't return when I send a quit message. And using `GetLastError()` after the `PostThreadMessage` call gives 1444 `ERROR_INVALID_THREAD_ID`.

I don't want to use `PeekMessage` because it uses 100% CPU, nor `Sleep` 'cos it's *apparently bad practice*.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see where you post ET_QUITLOOP. Usually such things are done using PostQuitMessage, but you don't use it as well. Possibly in `~event_thread` you wanted to post ET_QUITLOOP.

Comment: @alexfarber yeah sorry man i did mean to do that (posted an older version of the code) ... but even that doesn't help - WaitForSingleObject still never returns

Comment: I tried to read this but the macros are just too much. That's not how to write a program.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sorry, i just didn't want something as ugly as `((EVENT)(msg.wParam))((LPVOID)(msg.lParam))` in my code

Answer (score 3):

`ERROR_INVALID_THREAD_ID` means you tried to post a message to a thread ID that does not have a message queue.  So either you tried to post before the thread message loop was running, or after the thread had already terminated.

When your thread starts running, it should post a message to itself first to create a message queue, then set a signal to indicate that it is ready to receive messages, then finally enter its message loop.  In your class constructor, after calling `CreateThread()`, it can wait for that signal before then exiting.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <windows.h>
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#define ET_START WM_USER+1
#define ET_EVENTPUSH WM_USER+2
#define ET_QUITLOOP WM_USER+3

#define EVENT_HANDLER void
typedef void (*EVENT)(LPVOID);

//# event handler thread
class event_thread
{
private:
    //vars
    HANDLE  m_thread;   //event loop thread
    DWORD   m_id;       //thread id
    bool    m_ready;    // message queue is ready

    //thread procedure
    static DWORD WINAPI listener_loop(LPVOID);

public:
    //constructor
    event_thread();
    ~event_thread();

    //functions
    bool push_event(EVENT, LPVOID);
};

//# event handler thread
event_thread::event_thread()
{
    //create thread
    m_ready = false;
    m_thread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &listener_loop, this, 0, &m_id); 
    if (m_thread)
    {
        while (!m_ready)
            Sleep(10);
    } 
}
event_thread::~event_thread()
{
    //stop thread
    if (m_thread)
    {
        if (!PostThreadMessage(m_id, ET_QUITLOOP, 0, 0))
        {
            DWORD dw = GetLastError(); 
            ...
        } 
        WaitForSingleObject(m_thread, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(m_thread);
    }
}

bool event_thread::push_event(EVENT e, LPVOID p)
{
    return PostThreadMessage(m_id, ET_EVENTPUSH, (WPARAM)e, (LPARAM)p);
}

DWORD WINAPI event_thread::listener_loop(LPVOID param)
{
    event_thread *pThis = (event_thread*)param;

    MSG     msg;
    #define event_type  msg.message
    #define event_call  ((EVENT)(msg.wParam))
    #define event_param (LPVOID)(msg.lParam)

    PostThreadMessage(pThis->m_id, ET_START, 0, 0);
    pThis->m_ready = true;

    //while thread is alive
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        switch (event_type)
        {
        case ET_EVENTPUSH:
            event_call(event_param);
            break;
        case ET_QUITLOOP:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you do not like the `Sleep()` loop you can replace `m_ready` with a waitable event, and then use `SetEvent()` and `WaitForSingleObject()`.

Comment: I did that in a previous implementation and that worked fine (I used my own queue structure), but I just thought that since Windows makes its own message queue I'd give that a go... thanks still

Comment: You can certainly use a thread's native message queue, just keep in mind that a thread does not create its message queue until the first time it calls any user32 function, a new thread does not have a message queue by default, so better to call a user32 function earlier before the message loop starts running so you are in more control over when the queue is created, and then use a signal to know when the queue is available.

Comment: Well the problem I have _only_ occurs when the thread destructor is called at the end of `int main()` (after `return 0` is executed). If I create a thread class dynamically and destroy it before `return 0` then the code works perfectly well.